# Traversing all nodes in selected range

Tags: javascript, html

How can you retrieve all nodes within the selected range in javascript for example if i highlight the following nodes on this stackoverflow post is it possible to create a simple iterator given the base and extent node that walks the DOMTree between the two.
[image]

I've tried using Range and TreeWalker but haven't come up with anything i only ever get a range count of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a *copy* of the selected nodes by going through the selected range and clone the contents of the range selection. Collect all cloned nodes in a `DocumentFragment` object.

Then create a `TreeWalker` with the `DocumentFragment` object that has the collected elements and push each node to a new array.

The resulting array will be a list of all the nodes in the selection.

---

Run the example below and check the console of your browser after selecting text and clicking on the <kbd>Get selected nodes</kbd> button.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('get-nodes');

function getSelectedNodes() {
  const selection = document.getSelection();
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const nodeList = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; i++) {
    fragment.append(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
  }

  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(fragment);
  let currentNode = walker.currentNode;

  while(currentNode) {
    nodeList.push(currentNode);
    currentNode = walker.nextNode();
  }

  return nodeList;
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const nodeList = getSelectedNodes();
  console.log(nodeList);
});
```

```html
<button id="get-nodes">Get selected nodes</button>

<div class="s-prose js-post-body" itemprop="text">
  <p>I'm running spring cloud dataflow server in a container and was able to configure app logs to a specific folder that is brought outside of the container. However, I can't figure out how to store dataflow server logs themselves in a file.</p>
  <p>According to this:
    <a href="https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.7.2/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-logging" rel="nofollow noreferrer">https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.7.2/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-logging</a></p>
  <p>It should be plain and simple, just set LOG_PATH and that's pretty much it. But that does nothing. And when I look at logback-spring.xml in the jar file, I can see that:</p>
  <pre class="default s-code-block"><code class="hljs language-xml">    <span class="hljs-tag">&lt;<span class="hljs-name">root</span> <span class="hljs-attr">level</span>=<span class="hljs-string">"INFO"</span>&gt;</span>
        <span class="hljs-tag">&lt;<span class="hljs-name">appender-ref</span> <span class="hljs-attr">ref</span>=<span class="hljs-string">"STDOUT"</span>/&gt;</span>
        <span class="hljs-tag">&lt;/<span class="hljs-name">root</span>&gt;</span>
        </code></pre>
  <p>Which in my understanding is the reason why the logs don't go into the file, they just go to the console.</p>
  <p>Is there a way to override the appender-ref attribute in the logback-spring.xml with an environnment variable, or how can I get the dataflow server logs in a file?</p>
</div>
```